# assign member C function pointer with another member as default argument

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, function-calls

Let's say I have a C struct

```
struct MULTIPLY{
   int by;            //some factor to multiply, can be seen as instance id/key
   int (*get)(int c); //the function that actually returns the result
} multiply;
```

and that I want to assign the *multiply* instance using the following function

```
int product(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}
```

In main I would like  to assign to *multiply->get* a function that computes  the product of *multiply->by* and a new argument. I could do this by passing a pointer to the multiply instance, but I wonder if there is any way to call it without changing the signature of *get* function

```
multiply->by = 2;
multiply->get(int c) = product(multiply->by, c); ???

multiply->get(5); // 10
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers. Indeed, by default there's no way to do closures in C. I was looking for a workaround. I found 2 solutions but are quite limited. One is Blocks.h (also works with obj-C) needs to be compiled with Clang. The other is FFCALL (http://www.haible.de/bruno/packages-ffcall-README.html ), which is limited to some processor architectures.

So, in my case, I decided to just pass some pointers around to access the id (by, in this example). Pretty much what [Tomasz Lewowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2671214/tomasz-lewowski) suggested.

Comment: C does not directly support partial function application, as far as I know :) However, you can prepare a function which allocate a new structure and prepare a function using this structure... However, it'd be a nightmare to maintain

Comment: You cannot change function pointer's arguments once you declare it. You can do one thing, Delcare function pointer with variable number of arguments and then declare ALL your functions which you will assign to it with variable number of arguments and  then you can do what you want. I never did such thing... This tutorial might help -- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally C does not support partial function application, and you need all signatures and names set up in compilation time, and functions generally cannot be defined in runtime (kernel can load them, but let's ignore it - userspace apps don't do it). However...

*On some level of abstraction* this is possible (e.g. many interpreters written in C allow that), but for pure C it's not directly possible and, if you need to do it, you probably picked up a wrong language.

You can work around it by using an emulation of object-oriented approach (always passing another argument as `this` pointer). Pseudocode:

```
struct MULTIPLY{
   int by;            //some factor to multiply, can be seen as instance id/key

   // intended private
   int (*f)(int, int);
} multiply;

int call(MULTIPLY m, int i) {
  return *(m.f)(by, i);
}

MULTIPLY m = {2, product} // + allocation etc.;
call(m, 5); // actual call
```

It's much nicer in languages which really support object-oriented design, but you can do it in C as well - still, you need to remember about this additional argument (`this`, `context`, `self` or however you want to call it), which kinda messes up the code.

If you're ultra-determined to do it without any additional arguments, you can make a global `MULTIPLY` instance and use it from `call`. This would be something like:

```
// global scope!
MULTIPLY m;
int call(int i) {
    return *(m.f)(m.by, i);
}

// m initialization etc.
// some stuff happening
call(5);
```

But please, don't. It'll be ultra-hard to maintain, because of the global binding. Plus, it won't work exactly as a closure - once you change value in `m`, all places where you've passed `call` will start to behave differently (previous, object oriented approach will work properly everywhere).

Comment: `MULTIPLY* m = {2, product}` is incorrect: you're assinging a struct to a pointer variable. It should be `struct MULTIPLY m = {2, product};`. Also: the `struct MULTIPLY` is not `typedef`'ed, so it has to be  `struct MULTIPLY`

Comment: Thanks, probably this is the best solution at the moment. Was trying to avoid passing pointers around, because the code *call(m, 5); // actual call* would be in a lib that I don't want to have access to my program's variables. But for now, this should be good enough.

Comment: @ralux if you don't want `call` to access your variables you can use some pointer casting from your structure to structure exposed by `call` module, which would be first member of your structure (again, simulating OO-design - it'd be something like subclassing)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do closures like that in C.

You also can't run-time define functions, since C is a compiled language where the compiler is not available when the code runs.

Comment: @user694733 Gibberish. :) I missed a "'t", it should have been "can't" there in the beginning. Thanks, and fixed of course.